# How to avoid printing terminal space of cout statement

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm working on a function that prints the command line arguments in reverse order. The code is a little inelegant, I know, but I just need something that works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc==1){
      cout <<"\n";
    }

    for (int str=argc; str-1; str--){
      cout <<argv[str-1]<<" ";

    }
      if(argc>1){
        cout<<"\n";
      }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is thus: as it's currently programmed, this prints out a space after each command line argument is printed. However, I need there to be no space after the final command line argument is printed. How would I go about achieving this? Would I have to put in another if statement after the for loop?

Please forgive me if this is a basic question; I searched and couldn't find anything similar. I am just learning the basics of C++ now and there's nothing helpful in the current textbook I'm using so I'd be grateful for any assistance. Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I have to put in another if statement after the for loop?

Yes. That would be the simplest and clearest method. Perhaps something like:

```
for (int str=argc; str>1; str--){
    cout << argv[str-1];
    if (str != 2)
        cout << " ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you can, could you possibly help me figure out what kind of if statement I'd need? I'm really confused--would I make an if statement about str, or about argv?

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this code and it worked perfectly. I really appreciate the explanation and I'll be sure to take notes for future coding.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't necessarily need an if statement:

```
cout << argv[argc - 1];
for (int str = argc - 1; str > 1; str--)
{
    cout << " " << argv[str - 1];
}
```

Though it would be my first choice.

With if:

```
for (int str = argc; str > 1; str--)
{
    if(str > 2) cout << argv[str - 1] << " ";
    else cout << argv[str - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this and it's a success! However, now when I'm entering no command line arguments, there's a "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. I'll edit the main post to show!

Comment: Most of this pain is due to hooliaquoolia looping over `[argc, 2]` instead of looping from `[argc - 1, 1]`, which would likely be clearer to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You skip the `if statements`(unless you intent to do something very specific in them).

The `for` loop(along with ternary operator) itself would handle the case when you do not supply any command line argument. Second parameter in for loop `str > 1` would be false if there's no command line argument(since argc would be 1). So you can also get the same thing with:

```
int str;
for (str=argc; str > 1; str--)
    (str > 2)?cout<< argv[str-1]<<" " :cout<<argv[str-1]<<"\n";
```

If you still want to do it with the if statements, you can actually do it like

```
   int str; 
   if(argc==1)      //if argc equals 1
       cout <<"\n";
   else             //this would also include the argc > 1 cases.
    {
       for (str=argc; str > 1; str--) 
           cout <<argv[str-1]<<" ";  //print n-1 characters within the loop
       cout<<argv[str-1]<<"\n";  //and last one outside the for loop
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd write the code a tad differently. I think I'd use something closer to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "infix_iterator.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<char *> args {argv+1, argv+argc};

    if (args.empty())
        return 1;

    std::cout << "\n";           
    std::copy(args.rbegin(), args.rend(),
              infix_ostream_iterator<char *>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";      
}
```

This uses the `infix_ostream_iterator` I posted in [a question on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489), which makes a lot of tasks like this much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm completely new to C++, only started about two weeks ago, so most of this is unfamiliar to me--but thanks for showing me, I will be sure to come back to this when I get more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with having another if?

```
...
for (int str=argc; str-1; str--){
    cout << argv[str-1];
    if (str>2) cout << " ";
 }
...
```